# Opencart Image Manager Refresh Issue

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

My opencart 3.0.2.0 version has issue with Image Manager.

When i upload any photo the photo gets stored on the server but it doesn't appear on image manager.

Same happens when i try to delete photo or create a folder using image manager.

When i clear cookies or use another device the image appears on image manager and other updates also visible.

Please help. For adding new product i need to wait for image manager to get updated.

I tried disabling cloudflare but no success.

Comment: Cache module can create such issues, try disabling it.
Another way you can test is by removing the .htaccess cache code.

Comment: Thanks Rupak Nepali it was cache code in .htaccess which was affecting my opencart store. Resolved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If it is php8+ and your code is OC 3.0+ version(NOT FOR OC 4.0+) then please comment the code in image/resize function.
and return full filename. I am stopping cache creation.

change in both admin/model/tool/image.php and catalog/model/tool/image.php
PASTE THIS  CODE.

```
class ModelToolImage extends Model {
    public function resize($filename, $width, $height) {
        if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename) || substr(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)), 0, strlen(DIR_IMAGE)) != str_replace('\\', '/', DIR_IMAGE)) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
            return HTTPS_CATALOG . 'image/' . $filename;
        } else {
            return HTTP_CATALOG . 'image/' . $filename;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is php8+ and your code is OC 3.0+ version(NOT FOR OC 4.0+) then please replace the code in image/resize function.
and return full filename. I am stopping cache creation.

change in both admin/model/tool/image.php and catalog/model/tool/image.php
REPLACE THE CODE.

```
<?php
class ModelToolImage extends Model {
    public function resize($filename, $width, $height) {
        if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
            return HTTPS_CATALOG . 'image/' . $filename;
        } else {
            return HTTP_CATALOG . 'image/' . $filename;
        }       
    }
}
```

If you have any other version(php and OC)  then please check your folder permission(it should be 777 to cache folder) and check file name, there should  not be space in filename.